# Python- Unable to install pip on windows-No matching distribution found for pip

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install pip library on Windows 8. Current python version - 2.7.3. I downloaded get-pip.py from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

On command prompt (as Administrator) when I execute the following command
Python get-pip.py, I get following error. I am running this on my company network. Does this command expect me to provide ip address? I tried searching for a solution , but could not get satisfactory answer. Is there solution to it?If not is there any alternative to it? Please suggest

```
C:\windows\system32>cd C:\Python27

C:\Python27>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03654450>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03654490>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03654410>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03654150>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it',)': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03654550>: Failed to establish a new c
onnection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it',)': /simple/pip/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip

C:\Python27>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Windows [msi installers collection](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) with some Python packages for all Python versions, both 32 and 64 bit. You need to

1. Install setuptools
2. Install pip

After that I found pip at C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe. Now you can add it to your path

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected with internet.? 
First connect to internet and type this command again. If then also this problem doesn't solve. Download [python](https://www.python.org/) while installing there is option to install `pip`. Check that option and `pip` will be install in your system. 

There will be option to add pip into your `path variable` select that also.


If you face installing `pip` refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully install pip after disconnecting from company used internet connection. It was trying to somehow rejecting the connection request. Once I connected to local coffeeshops hotspot, it worked perfectly. Thank you for the support. Pip is installed on python 2.7.3

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\windows\system32>cd C:\Python27

C:\Python27>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
c:\users\aja67\appdata\local\temp\tmpvssw7v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\package
s\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, b
ut the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this p
latform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, whic
h can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to
 solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
security.html#snimissingwarning.
c:\users\aja67\appdata\local\temp\tmpvssw7v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\package
s\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is
 not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may
 cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Py
thon to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/
latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 328kB/s
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |################################| 71kB 597kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Successfully installed pip-9.0.1 wheel-0.29.0
c:\users\aja67\appdata\local\temp\tmpvssw7v\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\package
s\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is
 not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may
 cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Py
thon to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/
latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

C:\Python27>
```

Comment: sounds like a proxy server in your corporate network. Setting a proxy server in settings is not enough.
try python get-pip.py --proxy="http://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port"